# loop elements in array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to loop all children elements in array but it keeps looping only the first element however how much elements inside the parent

```
$(".js-drawer-open-cart").on("click", function (event) {
  var items = [];

  $(".cart__items .cart__item").each(function () {
    let product_title = $(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-title");
    let product_id = $(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-id");
    let product_variant = $(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-variant");
    let product_quantity = $(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-quantity");
    let product_price = $(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-price");

    dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null }); // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
    var item = {};

    item.item_name = product_title;
    item.price = product_price;
    item.item_brand = "El grande Porto";
    item.item_variant = product_variant;
    item.quantity = product_quantity;

    
    items.push(item);
  
  });

  dataLayer.push({
    event: "view_cart",
    ecommerce: {
      items: items,
    },
  });

});
```

Comment: can you show your html code ?

Comment: `$(this).find(".cart__item--name")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me thanks to epascarello's answer :

All i had to do is this :

```
$(this).find(".cart__item--name").attr("data-product-title");
```

Comment: Instead of saying thanks for someone else reply as an answer, just type it in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

`$(".cart__items .cart__item").each` iterates over all the elements that match the given selector, not the children of that element. If there should only be one match, try taking the first element and looping over its children?

Example: `$(".cart__items .cart__item").first().children().each`

Comment: Actually i want to target every div that has class of  .cart__item inside their parent .cart__items and loop them inside an array but it keeps repeating only first element 4 times